# ImportError: cannot import name FlowReader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use mitmproxy for importing flowreader in python 3 and Ubuntu. I get `ImportError` for `FlowReader` by executing the following line of code.

```
from mitmproxy.flow import FlowReader
```

Installing flow reader in the terminal fails when invoked by the command below.

```
pip3 install FlowReader
```

Please guide regarding possible solutions.

Comment: First of all, you can install `mitmproxy` by following this guide: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#installation-from-the-python-package-index-pypi. Also, I think `ubuntu` tag is not a valid tag because your question is not about ubuntu.

Comment: Please show the error for `pip3 install FlowReader`

Comment: @Ambitions I have already installed mitmproxy by "pip3 install mitmproxy". The error here is while importing FlowReader.

Comment: please share what is the error?

Comment: @classicdude7 The error states "ImportError: cannot import name Flow Reader" as mentioned above!

Comment: @Alexey Its "ImportError: cannot import name Flow Reader"

Comment: @MimiJam make sure you are using python 3.6 atleast and had installed pip3 for same version and then reinstall mitmproxy

Comment: @classicdude7 Ok, so my python version is 3.6.9 and pip3 version 9.0.1 already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing

```
from mitmproxy.io import FlowReader
```

Worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flow-parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mitmproxy.io import FlowReader
ImportError: No module named io